# Diagonal overflow scroll not working on chrome nor opera

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, scroll, cross-browser

Container(div) with set dimensions(constant), hides overflow(table). The diagonal scroll works fine on firefox and safari but chrome and opera do not scroll both dimensions at same time. Why?

fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/coolcatDev/kd75zyzk/1/

html:(for simplicity only one row->no y-overflow)

```
 <div class="wrap">
 <table>
 <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
        <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
        <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
        <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
        <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
        <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr> 
  </table>
  </div>
```

css:

```
.wrap{
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Googled it for you:

> Firefox and Chrome use two different JavaScript events for the mouse wheel, and the delta attribute is under a different name in each. Fortunately, there is a simple work-around that will be sufficient in most situations:

```
// For Chrome
window.addEventListener('mousewheel', mouseWheelEvent);

// For Firefox
window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', mouseWheelEvent);

function mouseWheelEvent(e) {
    var delta = e.wheelDelta ? e.wheelDelta : -e.detail;
}
```

[link](http://www.h3xed.com/programming/javascript-mouse-scroll-wheel-events-in-firefox-and-chrome)